# Tips for solving the exponential inequality: $x^{\ln(\sin x)}\ge1$

Tags: inequality

I am trying to find the solution to this inequality. I have tried applying the properties of logarithms without success.

$$x^{\ln(\sin x)}\ge1$$

Thanks for your tips to address it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, notice that your equation has sense only :

- for $x >0$ such that $\sin(x) >0$
- or $x \leq 0$ and $\sin(x)>0$, in the special case where $\ln(\sin(x))$ is a rational with an odd denominator. However, it is easy to see that in this case, there is no solution.

So we only consider the case where $x >0$ and $\sin(x) > 0$. Then you have
$$x^{\ln(\sin(x))} \geq 1 \Longleftrightarrow \exp \left( \ln(\sin(x))\ln(x)\right) \geq 1 \Longleftrightarrow \ln(\sin(x))\ln(x)\geq 0$$

But $\sin(x) \leq 1$, so $\ln(\sin(x)) \leq 0$. So if $\sin(x) \neq 1$, then where it is defined, the equation is equivalent to
$$\ln(x) \leq 0, \quad \text{i.e.} \quad x\leq 1$$

If $\sin(x)=1$, then the equation is automatically satisfied, so all the $(2k + \frac{1}{2})\pi$ are also solutions.
So the set of solutions of the original equation is
$$(0,1] \cup \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \lbrace (2k + \frac{1}{2})\pi\rbrace$$

Comment: Thanks, you're great!